# Exporting Content Type Data from Drupal 7 Database

Tags: sql-server, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-content-types, drupal-database

we're in the process of moving a client site from Drupal to Kentico and hoping to speed up some of the content creation by importing data for a custom content type.  I don't have development access to the Drupal site to do anything in PHP, I only have a full export of the database that we've restored in our MSSQL environment.

I've been looking through the database and trying to reverse engineer how this info is stored, but it's extremely complicated compared to exports we've used from other CMS platforms.  So far from what I can tell, I need to at least use a combination of data from the node table and the field_data_ tables.  For example, in Drupal there's a custom content type for award, so I'm looking at the data tables that start with field_data_field_award_, but those look like they need to be further joined to something else since they don't contain the data itself.

Any insight or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using only DB export to do migration can turn out to be unnecessarily complex.
An easy option would be to create REST endpoints in Drupal application to pull  content pages as JSON and then consume JSON in kentico to create content.

For example: **/api/awards** will render all awards pages in Drupal.

For Drupal 8 You can use views REST export to create this endpoint in minutes.
For Drupal 7 https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export can be used to export content as JSON